# how to add class path in websphere server.?

Tags: websphere

I need to add oracle.toplink.jar in classpath of WAS server but I am unable to put it. Please suggest. I tried to add this jar in start script of WAS server.

Comment: Can you please provide more detail about what your setup is, what you've tried, and what the results were?  It's hard for us to help out without knowing more about your situation.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to throw your jar in **WAS_HOME/lib/ext** directory, where WAS_HOME = The installation root of WebSphere Application Server.

**CAUTION**: Since this action changes the classpath of the WebSphere runtime, it could have unexpected consequences in case it conflicts with WAS libraries.

Another way to change the classpath of a deployed application is the create a **[shared library](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/tcws_sharedlib_create.html)** and reference it from your application.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Java virtual machine settings](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/urun_rconfproc_jvm.html) for options for changing server classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I guess one of your applications needs this library? Maybe just put it into shared libs (see Environment -> Shared libs in management console) and just reference it from applications (use Shared library references in application configuration).